# Where are the Act 3 lore books?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

D3's lore books are broken into People, Quest, Bestiary, and World lore book categories, though they are discovered in areas/zones, not by those categories. You'll see the one I'm missing below (**"Battlefield Reports"**), but I thought it would be more useful to make a full list instead of only asking for the one I need. Where are the Act 3 lore books, and when do they appear?

[image: Bestiary] [image: People] [image: World] [image: Quest]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [forum post](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271599310) includes details on how to find most but not all of the lore books for "Primary Sources", "History of Arreat" and "Espionage".

> **Primary Sources**
>
> Bloodstained Letter - The Keep (Needs confirmation)
>
> Ghom's Log - The Larder
>
> Journal of Hansan Haile, Captain - Bastion's Keep Stronghold, near Vidar
>
> Leah's Journal (13-16) - The Armory, below Leah
>
> Morgan's Journal (1-3) - Morgan's Satchel, Skycrown Battlements/Stonefort
>
> **Espionage**
>
> Battlefield Reports - Battlefields (walk backwards from Bridge of Korsikk, fallen soldier has blue exclamation point above head)
>
> Orders from Azmodan (1-6) - Messenger of Azmodan (Skycrown Battlements, Stonefort, The Keep, The Battlefields, Fields of Slaughter, Arreat Crater)
>
> **Historian of Arreat**
>
> Fall of the Barbarians (1-5) - Misplaced Packs, The Keep
>
> The History of Bastion's Keep - Librarian's Scrolls, The Keep

For the beast lore, I believe it is fairly straightforward to obtain by killing all the new monsters in Act 3, but I will look for a good source.  It is difficult to describe their locations since many are randomly generated.

Comment: One person states the *Battlefield Reports* are found in the [Keep's Depths Level 1](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Feu.battle.net%2Fd3%2Fru%2Fforum%2Ftopic%2F4309855665&act=url).  I'll wait for a confirmation before updating the answer.

Comment: I just located the bloodstained letter in "The Keep's Depths Level 1".

Comment: Battlefield Reports (scroll?) not found in the random spawning Battlefield Stores nor The Underbrigde. These were hard to spawn for me.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I tried to get the Battlefield Reports they were bugged; I don't know if this has been fixed yet.

I do know that some of the quest books and random spawns were bugged and fixed - Some of these were fixed but the battlefield reports werent fixed at that time.

They're supposed to spawn within the Battlefield Stores, just that the tile where the journal drops is bugged currently. Once fixed the Battlefield Reports will spawn in this zone, the last time I tested this nothing dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Battlefield Reports are now in the game after patch 1.0.4 They actually spawn in the Battle Fields (Go figure ;P) Near Arreat Gate from an NPC with a blue ! over his head. There are quite a few of these guys but only one of them is your man, I made a quick youtube video showing where I found him, as well as where it seems would be the best spot to look first. Also it proves that the achievement for getting all the lore books now works as well :)

Hope this helps and happy hunting!