# Where is the battlefield report for the Act III achievement Espionage?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the Act 3 lore books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69132/where-are-the-act-3-lore-books)

I've read too many conflicting reports to not ask the question here, where can this journal be located?  It's one of my few remaining Act III quests.

Comment: @fbueckert Possibly but even so this particular book is generating a lot more aggrivation in the world at large than the general answer suggests :)

Comment: That doesn't mean it gets it's own question; it's already been asked.  If you want an update on the answers, offer a bounty or request an update through a comment.

Comment: @fbueckert That's ok, closing as duplicate is correct and will at least redirect to the correct question now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now the item do not drop in-game.

> The achievement "Espionage" cannot be completed because the lore
>   "Battlefield Reports" doesn't drop in game.

[Here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4916972036) you have the blue post which states the bug. Check under achievements!

Hope they will fix this soon!

Comment: As of v1.04 patch this is now achievable

Comment: Yes it is in 1.04 patch notes indeed :) thanks for pointing this out